# how to handle cookie popup with python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am having problem with handling this cookie popup on this url https://wax.atomichub.io/drops/36636. I don't know what code should i write for this in python so that **Accept All** button is clicked and the actual page is visible. need help!

Answer (score 0):

that **accept all** is web element and you can use below xpath to locate the element and it would be simply clicking on a web element.

You can try the below code :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\ect\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://wax.atomichub.io/drops/36636")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All']"))).click()
print("Click operation is successful")
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```